# Django Testing: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django framework & I am trying write some tests for my apps in the project.Currently I have two apps `hoardings` & `clients` both have same basic CRUD features.For testing purpose I have created a test directory & it looks like this

```
clients
 - tests
  -__init__.py
  - test_views.py
```

That's how I am maintaining my tests for both the apps.My test_views.py has following code,

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from hoardings.models import State, City
from clients.models import Client


class ClientManagementTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.state = State.objects.create(desc='West Bengal')

        self.city = City.objects.create(state=self.state, desc='Kolkata')

        self.client = Client()

    def test_client_creation_form_can_be_rendered(self):

        response = self.client.get(reverse('clients:create'))

        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # check if csrf token is present
        self.assertContains(response, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken')

        # Check that the response contains a form.
        self.assertContains(response, '<form')

        # assert the context values
        self.assertIn('url', response.context)
        self.assertIn('heading', response.context)
        self.assertIn('states', response.context)
        self.assertIn('client_types', response.context)
```

As you can see in the setup method I am creating an object of `Client` which is used to send the request.But every time I run the tests I get following errors,

> ERROR: test_client_creation_form_can_be_rendered
> (tests.test_views.ClientManagementTest)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/home/ropali/Development/PythonWorkspace/hms_venv/hms/clients/tests/test_views.py",
> line 19, in test_client_creation_form_can_be_rendered response =
> self.client.get(reverse('clients:create')) AttributeError: 'Client'
> object has no attribute 'get'

As per my understanding It means that client object is not being created so it cannot find the get attribute & I get the similar error for the POST request as well.
But one thing is bugging me that I have similar test setup for the `hoardings` app it runs perfectly fine.
Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here.Let me know if you need other details.

Comment: Your client is an instance of what appears to be a model? You should use [django.test.Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example) to test your view responses

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks buddy..I am dumb I shoud've noticed that thing.Now I renamed my test client import and it does not throw that error any more.